# How can i use dropdown button 2 with keyboard in windows application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I have tried many times to change its source but I can not understand how and what logic i have to add for  control dropdownmenu with keyboard. you can find it's source in ExternalLibraries/Dart Packages / dropdown_button_2

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.